# Doubt regarding $∀x(P(x)→Q(x))→(∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x)))$ validity

Tags: logic

I know this is valid. But from LHS we can infer only for same $x$ for both $P$ and $Q$. So, I want to know how we can directly arrive at $P(a)→Q(b)$, when only information we have is $P(a)→Q(a)$ and $P(b)→Q(b)$.

Comment: We have $\forall x (Px → Qx)$ and we assume $\forall x Px$. Then we derive $Pa \to Qa$ and $Pa$ respectively. From them : $Qa$.

Comment: But $a$ is whatever; thus, we can "generalize" on it.

Comment: Consider domain of disourse consisiting of {a,b}. From premises we have P(a)→Q(a) and P(b)→Q(b). Now **logically** how can we say about P(a)→Q(b) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If P holds for all x and for each x, P(x) implies Q(x), then Q holds for all x.
You never need P(a) implies Q(b), but you have guaranteed, on RHS that P(x) for all x, and by LHS, P(x) implies Q(x).

As an example, let the domain be {a, b}.
Suppose LHS valid. Then P(a) implies Q(a) and P(b) implies Q(b). Now, on RHS, suppose for all x, P(x). That is, we have P(a) and P(b) valid. By LHS, P(a) implies Q(a), then Q(a) is valid. Also, P(b) implies Q(b), then Q(b) is valid. Then Q holds for both a and b, that is, Q holds for all x. Then we proved "(for all x P(x)) implies (for all x Q(x))". Note that we are NOT proving "for all x (P(x) implies for all x Q(x))".

Comment: Consider domain of disourse as{a,b}. From premises we have P(a)→Q(a) and P(b)→Q(b). Now **logically** how can we say about P(a)→Q(b) ?

Comment: First of all consider only premise this ∀x(P(x)→Q(x)) . After that we have to prove ∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x))

Comment: What you're saying is different from what is written. You are saying "for all x, y, P(x) implies Q(y)". This is different from "for all x P(x) implies for all x Q(x)" . Read it as "the fact that P holds for all x implies that Q also holds for all x".

Comment: I am saying all we have is this ∀x(P(x)→Q(x)) and the domain of discourse. Now, I am asking how we can prove it to ∀x(P(x)→Q(x))→(∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x))) . I do not want to take this formula as given and then proving it correct. I want to know how to derive it using a example. And that example is using domain of discourse {a,b}

Comment: Suppose LHS valid. Then P(a) implies Q(a) and P(b) implies Q(b). Now, on RHS, suppose for all x, P(x). That is, we have P(a) and P(b) valid. By LHS, P(a) implies Q(a), then Q(a) is valid. Also, P(b) implies Q(b), then Q(b) is valid. Then Q holds for both a and b, that is, Q holds for all x. Then we proved "(for all x P(x)) implies (for all x Q(x))".

Comment: Note that we are NOT proving "for all x (P(x) implies for all x Q(x))", that is what you're reading from the sentence above.

Comment: Yeah, this was the explanation I was looking for. Please update your answer with this example.

Comment: If $\forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ then $P(a) \rightarrow Q(a)$ and $P(b) \rightarrow Q(b)$. From this we can conclude that $(P(a) \land P(b)) \rightarrow (Q(a) \land Q(b))$, which is what the right hand side claims. There is no claim that $P(a) \rightarrow Q(b)$.

Comment: @gandalf61 But (∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x))) becomes invalid then if P(a)->Q(b) is not true.

Comment: It doesn't. I repeat: you're reading it the wrong way. You do not need that "for each x, the validity of P(x) implies the validity of Q(y), for each y". You need "P being valid for every element implies Q is also valid for every element".

Comment: What you need to understand is the difference between $(\forall x P(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x Q(x))$, which is correct, and $\forall x \forall y (P(x) \rightarrow Q(y))$, that is what you're trying to say.

Comment: @user10143594 Not so. Suppose $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$ are true and $P(b)$ and $Q(b)$ are false. Then $P(a) \rightarrow Q(b)$ is false because we have $P(a) \land \lnot Q(b)$. But  $(\forall x P(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x Q(x))$ is true because $\forall x P(x)$ is false.

Comment: @gandalf61 I agree with you. Can you edit this answer or please a new answer including this point.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean valid in a semantic or deductive way?

Deductively it can be shown as follows:

Assume $\forall x( P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$

Suppose $ \forall x P(x)$,
Therefore $P(x)$ and as such $Q(x)$ by the assumption. As such $\forall x Q(x)$.

That completes the proof. Since natural deduction using the usual rules is semantically valid, then so is the formula. It's valid even constructively.

For an example, let the domain be $A=\{a,b\}$. Now assume:

$$\forall x( P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$$

As such:

$$ P(a) \rightarrow Q(a),P(b) \rightarrow Q(b)$$

Now assume:
$P(a),P(b)$

Therefore by the above: $Q(a),Q(b)$. Since $a,b$ is the whole domain we are allowed to bring in the "for all" quantifier.

And that concludes the proof. Note that model theory would be inconsistent if this was not the case. By the above proof the sentence should hold for all possible worlds.

Finally, there is small error in the question. $P(a)\rightarrow Q(b)$ is not the case.

Comment: I am saying all we have is this ∀x(P(x)→Q(x)) and the domain of discourse. Now, I am asking how we can prove it to ∀x(P(x)→Q(x))→(∀x(P(x))→∀x(Q(x))) . I do not want to take this formula as given and then proving it correct. I want to know how to derive it using a example. And that example is using domain of discourse {a,b}.

Comment: @user10143594 Okay, so you want to show that there is some model that satisfies it? I will edit the post...

Comment: If P(a) and P(b) are true and then obviously Q(a) and Q(b) are true. So, P(a) -> Q(b)

Comment: @user10143594 The first statement does not infer that $P(a)\rightarrow Q(b)$. It's only after that, when it's assumd that $P(a)$ IS true for all a, that you can make such inference. Sure, that does imply it.

Comment: In my above comment, all I wrote was based on your answer only

Comment: @user10143594 Do you have a question? My meaning is that $P(a)\rightarrow Q(b)$ is not the case under the first implication if that was what you were wondering.